# What transparent casings are commonly used for smaller devices with a display

Tags: arduino-uno

Not exactly Arduino-specific, but if you want to get a daily usable device (instead of a floating wire connection on your table) you eventually want to put your (Arduino-based) device into a nice casing. What are the different types of cases that people use?

I found soap cases as well as kitchen boxes (used one [large cheese box](https://github.com/vmcrash/ArduinoDccAccessoryCentral/blob/master/screenshots/front.jpg) from Mepal Rosti).

Comment: I found display cases for signed baseballs/golfballs/softballs useful for projects where I wanted all the pretty internals to be visible.  Just buy two - one to scratch up while planning, and then a clean one for the final result.

Answer (score 4):

So far we have used:

ABS cases (pic camdenboss.com):

[image]

Small pelicases (convenient to open, pic pelican-case.com):

[image]

3D printed cases with a clear perspex window (pic instructables.com):

[image]

I've seen other people use laser cut perspex (pic spikenzielabs.com):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have affordable access to a laser cutter, then you could laser cut a box to exactly match your project.

Laser cutters typically come with software that reads SVG or DXF files. 
Find out what file types are used, then search the web for something like "laser cut box design tool SVG", and you'll find a bunch of ways to make the box outline.

For example, this [laser cut box web site](http://boxmaker.rahulbotics.com/) generates a pdf file, which you can 'print'. You fill in a few parameters, and it does the rest, generating all the profiles for interlocking edges. Even though the edges are interlocking, you might want to add some glue to make it more robust.

An advantage of laser cutting is you can choose the materials. Maybe you'd like wood, with a transparent red acrylic lid.

A further advantage, if your laser can read things like SVG or DXF, is you could use a CAD or drawing program to modify the box. So, for example, you could 'etch' labels onto a control panel, or cut extra holes to mount LEDs. Or just decorate the outside of the box.

Comment: Yes, having a laser cutter would be handy. Unfortunately, that's no option for where I'm living. Nonetheless, thanks for the link, though the resulting pdf files waste a lot of material because of inefficient placing.

Comment: @Thomas S. I apologise for the poor choice of boxmaker. I thought I'd one which created DXF or SVG but I seen to have lost it. I'll ask a friend for the one they like, and update my answer if it is better. Do you not live in a country with MakerSpaces? Some of them offer to cut designs quite cheaply. I am not against ready made cases, it's just they often need to be cut anyway for cables, or to make components, like sockets, LEDs, etc. usable. I also like the idea of engraving labels onto it.